# Spacemacs terminal emulator share history with zsh

Tags: spacemacs, term

In plain vanilla emacs, I can `M-x term RET RET`. This starts zsh. And it 'shares' history with my non-emacs terminals.

So, I can `ESC /` and search for commands, etc.

How do I achieve that for spacemacs?

Comment: could you just do the same thing?  i just tried it and was able to see bash history from an external terminal

Comment: @GrantShangreaux in my case, it produces an error:
error in process filter. Invalid face: unspecified.